# Ubuntu Software Center does not start on 10.10, Cannot upgrade to 11.04

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, software-center

Softwre center does not start on my 10.10.It used to work before. I noticed this recently. On clicking Ubuntu Software center in the Applications menu, I can see the Starting Ubuntu Software center button in the taskbar, which disappears after a while, but the software center does not appear. I cannot install deb files using software center either, since the same thing happens(using gdebi to install deb files now). On running software-center from terminal, I get the following.

```
$ software-center
2011-06-04 23:01:25,084 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/widgets/mkit_themes.py', 675, 'retrieve')'
2011-06-04 23:01:25,083 - root - WARNING - No styling hints for Wasp-Murrine were found... using Human hints.

(software-center:7715): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_loadable_icon_load: assertion `G_IS_LOADABLE_ICON (icon)' failed

(software-center:7715): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_loadable_icon_load: assertion `G_IS_LOADABLE_ICON (icon)' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 90, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterApp(datadir, xapian_base_path, options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/app.py", line 312, in __init__
    self.view_switcher = ViewSwitcher(self.view_manager, datadir, self.db, self.cache, self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 59, in __init__
    store = ViewSwitcherList(view_manager, datadir, db, cache, icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 321, in __init__
    self._update_channel_list()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 398, in _update_channel_list
    self._update_channel_list_available_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 420, in _update_channel_list_available_view
    for channel in self.channel_manager.channels:
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 65, in channels
    return self._get_channels()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 279, in _get_channels
    channel_query=for_purchase_query)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._channel_icon = self._get_icon_for_channel(channel_name, channel_origin, channel_component)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 425, in _get_icon_for_channel
    channel_icon = self._get_icon("emblem-money")
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 458, in _get_icon
    icon = AnimatedImage(self.icons.load_icon(icon_name, self.ICON_SIZE, 0))
glib.GError: Failed to load icon
```

I upgraded all the packges using Update Manager to the latest ones. I reinstalled software-center from synaptic. Still no luck. How do I go about resolving this?

And I don't know if this is related, but upgrading 10.10 to 11.04 using the alternative iso fails with the following error.

```
Could not mark ubuntu-desktop for upgrade.
```

last part of apt.log file, which mentions both software-center and ubuntu-desktop

```
Investigating (7) software-center [ i386 ] < 3.0.8 -> 4.0 > ( gnome )
Broken software-center:i386 Depends on python-webkit [ i386 ] < 1.1.8-0ubuntu2 -> 1.1.8-1ubuntu2 > ( python )
  Considering python-webkit:i386 10000 as a solution to software-center:i386 10000
  Removing software-center:i386 rather than change python-webkit:i386
Investigating (7) libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.8.6-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libnspr4-0d:i386 Conflicts on libnspr4 [ i386 ] < none -> 4.8.7-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 2:4)
  Considering libnspr4:i386 10000 as a solution to libnspr4-0d:i386 10000
  Removing libnspr4-0d:i386 rather than change libnspr4:i386
Investigating (8) ubuntu-desktop [ i386 ] < 1.207 -> 1.220 > ( metapackages )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:i386 Depends on software-center [ i386 ] < 3.0.8 -> 4.0 > ( gnome )
  Considering software-center:i386 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:i386 10000
  Considering software-center:i386 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:i386 10000
Investigating (8) xulrunner-1.9.2 [ i386 ] < 1.9.2.17+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.10.1 > ( devel )
Broken xulrunner-1.9.2:i386 Depends on libnspr4-0d [ i386 ] < 4.8.6-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 4.7.3-0ubuntu1~)
  Considering libnspr4-0d:i386 10000 as a solution to xulrunner-1.9.2:i386 10000
  Removing xulrunner-1.9.2:i386 rather than change libnspr4-0d:i386
Investigating (9) ubuntu-desktop [ i386 ] < 1.207 -> 1.220 > ( metapackages )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:i386 Depends on software-center [ i386 ] < 3.0.8 -> 4.0 > ( gnome )
  Considering software-center:i386 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:i386 10000
  Considering software-center:i386 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:i386 10000
Investigating (9) yelp [ i386 ] < 2.30.1-0ubuntu1 -> 3.0.0-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken yelp:i386 Depends on xulrunner-1.9.2 [ i386 ] < 1.9.2.17+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.10.1 > ( devel )
  Considering xulrunner-1.9.2:i386 10000 as a solution to yelp:i386 10000
  Removing yelp:i386 rather than change xulrunner-1.9.2:i386
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Problem..
Well it looks like it can't find an *emblem-money* icon.
The first thing it complains about is Wasp-Murrine (a custom theme).

I suggest you change your theme back to humanity and see if that fixes it.
for me the emblem-money icons are found in package `humanity-icon-theme`.
You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install humanity-icon-theme
```

If that doesn't work you could try upgrading without the gui.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here's how I "fixed" the issue. I removed software-center and ubuntu-desktop. Then I did a offline upgrade using the alternate disc. The upgrade on finishing gave me an error saying that the upgrade couldn't complete successfully and some packages were not installed. On reboot, I booted into 11.04 which gave a "System has detected a problem.. Report Problem Dialog". On going to Update Manager, it offered me a Partial upgrade, consisting of removing 2 packages, installing 73 packages and upgrading 319 packages.

Comment: I disabled some third party ppa's. I did a `sudo apt-get remove` on the two "to be removed" packages, followed by a `sudo apt-get upgrade` which installed and upgraded the required packages. My 11.04 is working fine now.

Comment: I might have manually installed ubuntu-desktop and software-center too, but I am not sure.